# Providing simple address/driving directions with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, driving-directions

I have been pouring over the Google Maps API information, and for the life of me I can't seem to find an example, or figure out the exact right way of doing what I want.

From a simple HTML layout I need to display a Google Map, with a single address listed as a marker, with the user having the ability to click "Get Directions" or something similar to get driving directions.

I have a full address, but no Latitude or Longitude information.  Does anyone have a good pointer, or a simple example of doing this that they could share?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use the API for this.  You can send a query directly to a Google maps object in an iframe.

For example, to show the White House:

```
 <iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?geocode=&q=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Avenue%20NW,%20washington,%20DC" width="100%" height="300" >
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
 </iframe>
```

The resulting map has a single address marker which allows the user to get directions.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out a little bit ago, was over complicating things a bit!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latitude and longitude of any address using "geocoder services" there are lots of services available for free. [geocoder.us](http://geocoder.us) is a free service through which you can "geocode" any address in the USA. Also, look at the site http://googlemapsbook.com/geocoders/ to find out more such geocoders. However, I don't think there is an easy way to get the driving directions, As far as I know the Google Maps API doesn't expose such functionality.

Comment: Sure it does! See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GDirections

It may be that using the API is overkill for this particular case but the functionality is definitely available.